# Android app to view multiple document types

Tags: android

I know this has been asked before but i couldnt find any links here or in web.

I need to open .pdf, .doc, .ppt, .xls document types from our server **within my android application without saving the files to device or using options like google viewer because of security reasons.**

I know that android does not have built in support for this but i looking for any third party options paid or free for my app

One solution i read about is to package another app (like smart office) with in my app and open the docs using that. Can someone post me more information regarding that (packing apps with in app and opening using intent).

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you try yourself first. That's the best way to learn.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know what you've been reading.. But, Android does have support for this, its all about mimeTypes and how you handle those mimeTypes (Intent) in your app. Look at @
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/data-element.html

That should get your started.